# removing index number/rowname in vector in r

Tags: r

Consider a data table with a column named `final`:

```r
a = data.table::data.table(final = c("name1","name2","name3"))
```

I want to use each element of the column final in a loop but I want it without its index number.

Even when I do

```r
rownames(a) <- NULL
```

and try

```r
a$final[1]
```

it shows

```
[1] name1
```

I want this without the index number `[1]`, i.e, just

```
name1
```

Comment: That's just how R prints vectors (including length-1 vectors). If you type `1` into the console and hit return, R prints it as `[1] 1`. The `[1]` is just used for the print display. It is not a part of the result. If you want to display the result of `a$final[1]` without seeing a `[1]` in the output, try `cat(a$final[1])`

Comment: Right, just part of the print method. Or `cat(a$final[1], '\n')`.

Comment: @AllanCameron, i understand the cat solution but the issue is I want to use the output of a$final[1] as a control variable in a regression, the regression will be run in a loop for a$final[1]..[2]...[3] and so on..if there i use cat(a$final[1]) it doesnt work since it just appears as cat..any solution so that the index in not there when i put it in a equation?

Comment: @sashahafner, please see the above comment

Comment: I think what you search for is `lm(reformulate(a$final[i], 'Y'), your_data)`. Try to put this line into your loop.

Comment: @jalajpathak I am not sure I understand. Could you clarify your question? And give us some reproducible code that shows the problem? I don't see how whether or not a [1] is printed when the value of an object is displayed is related to using the values in object `a$final[1]` in some operation. Are you trying to construct a formula with the value in `a$final[1]`?

Comment: @sashahafner, yes, i was tryng to use in the formula. i specified the data table in the question and the rest in the comment by darren. The reformulate thing worked for me.